# Reading and finding texts in a file

Tags: c#

I'm reading string data from inside a file. When I search the string data I read, the value I want does not seem to exist. Can you help with this topic?

The word I'm trying to search is: **GTA:SA:MP**

[image]

The code I use is:

```
static byte[] ReadFile(string filePath)
{
    byte[] buffer;
    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    try
    {
        int length = (int)fileStream.Length;  // get file length
        buffer = new byte[length];            // create buffer
        int count;                            // actual number of bytes read
        int sum = 0;                          // total number of bytes read

        // read until Read method returns 0 (end of the stream has been reached)
        while ((count = fileStream.Read(buffer, sum, length - sum)) > 0)
            sum += count;  // sum is a buffer offset for next reading
    }
    finally
    {
        fileStream.Close();
    }
    return buffer;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    byte[] data = ReadFile(@"FILE.exe");
    string result = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
    if (result.Contains("GTA:SA:MP"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Found");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Not found");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The answer to me: Not found

Comment: why not use `File.ReadAllText`?

Comment: I think it will be slow for large files. It also doesn't give the result I want.

Comment: So you present an image as a proof that the value exists. But it doesn't looks like a hex-editor, there could be bytes in-between `"GTA:SA:MP"` which you don't see. Try to use hex-editor.

Comment: @BurakAkat your code is doing an equivalent form of it. if the file is binary you could try reading thru it in chunks.

Comment: Instead of reading binary as text and searching for a string, use [ReadAllBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readallbytes) to read bytes and search for sequence of bytes as well.

Comment: Why are you interpreting an .exe file as ASCII? That almost certainly won't work. You would need to have some prior knowledge of the structure of the program to at least be able to recognise which regions are embedded data and which are executable, at a minimum.

Comment: @Sinatr When I searched with the Hex editor, I accessed the following data. How can I search this data?

https://i.imgur.com/ccDNWAp.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple problems.  As others have pointed out if your source is bytes then you should compare bytes not strings.  Otherwise you have encoding issues.  Second issue is you're using a buffer but  you're not checking for any boundary conditions - where the pattern you're searching for is split across the buffer size boundary.  One simple way to do something like this is treat the source as a stream and just check byte by byte.  I'll include an example using a simple state machine made from local functions.

I used the local functions just because it seemed fun, you can do this in a myriad of ways..

```
    static void Main(string[] _)
    {
        byte[] target = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("2:30pm");
        long offsetInSource = 0;
        int indexOfTarget = 0;
        long current = 0;
        bool found = false;

        Func<byte, byte, bool> match = CheckStart;

        using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open("foo.txt", FileMode.Open)))
        {
            while (current < reader.BaseStream.Length)
            {
                var b = reader.ReadByte();
                var t = target[indexOfTarget];

                if (match(t, b))
                {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }

                ++current;
            }
        }

        if (found)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Found matching pattern at: {offsetInSource}");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Did not find pattern");
        }

        bool CheckStart(byte t, byte b)
        {
            if (t == b)
            {
                offsetInSource = current;
                if (++indexOfTarget == target.Length)
                    return true;

                match = CheckRest;
            }

            return false;
        }

        bool CheckRest(byte t, byte b)
        {
            if (t == b)
            {
                if (++indexOfTarget == target.Length)
                    return true;
            }
            else
            {
                indexOfTarget = 0;
                match = CheckStart;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If your file is huge, you can read file as text in 500 characters (for example) and store them into a string variable and search your phrase in this variable. If your phrase not found, read another 500 characters by 450 (500-50) offset and store them into a string variable and search your phrase in this variable. Do this loop until your phrase found or EOF reached.